# React.js download large file got error. How to set the request header for downloading?

Tags: reactjs

Code first:

```
 fetch(somerouting, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: someheaders(including authenitcation)
            })
                .then(result => {
                    if (result.status === 401) {
                        //do something
                    } else if (result.status >= 400) {
                        //do something
                    } else {
                        let filename = result.headers.get("content-disposition").split("\"")[1];
                        result.blob()
                            .then(blob => {
                                let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                                let a = document.createElement('a');
                                a.href = url;
                                a.download = filename;
                                a.click();
                            });
                      
                    }
                }).catch((error) => {
               // do something
            });
        };
```

This is the typical code for downloading a file with the trick to set the header:
https://blog.bguiz.com/post/90559955303/file-download-with-http-request-header/

The error I got is
`net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 200` 
The backend got a "Channel failed" error.

I did a search and this seem due to the blob used in the download has the size limitation.

Is there any other way that can download large files? My files is close to 1G.

Any other approaches to set the request header for downloading?